# Iterative partial sum on rows with the same dates in R

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I would like to do some computation on several rows in a table.
I created an exemple below:

```
  library(dplyr)
  set.seed(123)
  year_week <- c(200045:200053, 200145:200152, 200245:200252)
  input <- as.vector(sample(1:10,25,TRUE))
  partial_sum <- c( 20,12,13,18,12,13,4,15,9,13,10,20,11,9,9,5,13,13,,8,13,11,15,14,7,14)
  df <- data.frame(year_week, input, partial_sum)
```

Given are the columns *input* and  *year_week*. The later represents dates but the values are numerical in my case with the first 4 digits as years and the last two as the working weeks for that year.
What I need, is to iterate over each week in each year and to sum up the values from the same weeks in the other years and save the results into a column called here *partial_sum*. The current value is excluded from the sum.
The week 53 in the lap year 2000 will get the same treatment but in this case I have only one lap year therefore its value 3 doesn't change.

Any idea on how to make it?
Thank you

Comment: Is the expected output in partial_sum correct?.  I see that you are taking the `sample` without `set.seed`

Comment: sorry, I've corrected it now

Answer (score 2):

I would expect something like this would work, though as pointed out in comments your example isn't exactly reproducible.

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  mutate(week = substr(year_week, 5, 6)) %>%
  group_by(week) %>%
  mutate(result = sum(input))
```

Comment: I've  added the correction. The result is not quite what I need as it sum up every thingle column.

Comment: Is it a sum of previous years only or all years except the current year? If you need to omit the current year, just subtract it from the sum: `partial_sum = sum(input) - input)`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps - grouped by 'week' by taking the `substring`, get the difference between the `sum` of 'input' and the 'input'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
   group_by(week = substring(year_week, 5)) %>%
   mutate(partial_sum2 = sum(input) - input)
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution is almost correct. What is missing is to check for the leap year namely, if there are other  53 weeks in the data to apply the same rule and if not, to keep the value from input.